# Why is my code not incrementing?

Tags: java

So my professor had us do an assignment that asks the user for 5 numbers that are valid (51-99) and unique (non-repeating). I just can't figure out why my nested for loop inside the while loop is not incrementing the `i`, I suspect it is the `break;` but without that the for loop keeps looping. Any help would be awesome. Thank you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] userArray;
    userArray = new int[5];
    int real = 0;

    System.out.println("Please print out 5 numbers between 50 and 100. ");
    Scanner entry = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (real < 5) {
        int count = entry.nextInt();
        boolean aCount = isValid(count);

        if (aCount == true) {
            for (int i =0; i < userArray.length; i++) {
                userArray[i] = count;
                real++;
                break;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("That is not a valid number.");
        }
    }
}

public static boolean isValid(int a) {
    if (a > 50 && a < 100) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You `for-loop` will fill the `userArray` with the last value that the user entered, instead, you only need to use `real` as the index of the next vaue

Comment: The `break` breaks you out of the for loop; you might as well not have a for loop if you have the `break` statement.

Comment: What makes you think that it is not incrementing?

Comment: MadProgramer, can you explain more on the (real)?

Comment: Gendarme, I debugged it and the integer i is not showing up.

Comment: @EricGuo `i` won't show in debugger until you are inside the `for` loop, because it doesn't exist *outside* the loop.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood. I thought you were saying that `real++;` is not working. Your `i` is not incrementing because your loop ends after the first iteration because of `break;` as you correctly suspected. If you don't use `break`, the loop will iterate five times. Is that not what you want? I don't see why you need that `break`.

Comment: every time you reach the `for` loop, `int i = 0` is executed, that means you are always saving the number in the first position of the array; for this task you do not need to use a inner loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it guys! I just had to remove the for loop and put this in:

```
            userArray[i] = count;
            i++;
            real++;
```

Thank you  schmidt73 and everyone that helped!

Comment: Without a for-loop there is no `i`, is there?

Comment: There is, I just added int i = 0; at the top so it wouldn't be looped.

Comment: Don't forget to check for duplicates (*unique (non-repeating)*).

Answer (score 1):

```
    int i=0;
    while (real < 5) {
    int count = entry.nextInt();
    boolean aCount = isValid(count);
    if (aCount == true) {
            userArray[i++] = count;
            real++;

    } else {
        System.out.println("That is not a valid number.");
    }
}
```

I guess this is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Answers are not for guessing. True, this is not a good question, but let's not clutter it down even more with bad answers.

Answer (score 0):

First, you also need to test if the array contains the value you are trying to add (in validate). You could do something like

```
public static boolean isValid(int[] arr, int real, int a) {
    if (a > 50 && a < 100) {
        for (int i = 0; i < real; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == a) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then your `main` method might be written like

```
int[] userArray = new int[5];
int real = 0;
System.out.println("Please print out 5 numbers between 50 and 100. ");
Scanner entry = new Scanner(System.in);
while (real < 5) {
    int count = entry.nextInt();
    if (isValid(userArray, real, count)) {
        userArray[real++] = count;
    } else {
        System.out.println("That is not a valid number.");
    }
}
System.out.println("The array contains: " + Arrays.toString(userArray));
```